# When running Bundle against local Gems, what steps must be taken to make the new Gem code take effect?

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

e.g. I have a project "Blog" which uses a [local Gem](https://coderwall.com/p/tqdrhq/work-against-local-gems-without-modifying-your-gemfile) "StringFormatter".

Now I make a modification to StringFormatter, how do I see this take effect in Blog?

Answer (score 1):

The only step required is to git commit the local Gem.

You don't have to re-run bundle. And (as you'd expect), you don't have to push it anywhere.

For Rails, you also have to exit the console and restart it. (I found a "reload!" on console alone doesn't update from the local Gem, so for Rails, you also have to exit the console and restart it.)

*(Answering my own question here as it's a common FAQ which isn't answered in any of the docs about this feature.)*